# testing angular http interceptor - expect called before intercept returns

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have a simple `HttpInterceptor` for setting a loading state. Here is the code

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _loadingService: LoadingService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const id = uuid();

    this._loadingService.startLoading(id);

    return next
      .handle(req)
      .pipe(finalize(() => this._loadingService.completeLoading(id)));
  }
}
```

and these are the tests

```
describe('LoaderHttpInterceptor', () => {
  let mockLoadingService: LoadingService;
  let injector: Injector;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let controller: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LoadingService,
          useValue: { startLoading: jest.fn(), completeLoading: jest.fn() },
        },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: LoaderHttpInterceptor,
          multi: true,
          deps: [LoadingService],
        },
      ],
    });
    mockLoadingService = TestBed.get(LoadingService);
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    controller = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  describe('intercept', () => {
    it('should call loader service startLoading', () => {
      const url = faker.internet.url();
      httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(() => {
        expect(mockLoadingService.startLoading).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      });

      controller.expectOne(url).flush('');
    });

    it('should call loader service completeLoading on success', async(() => {
      const url = faker.internet.url();

      httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'text' })
        .subscribe(() => {
        expect(mockLoadingService.completeLoading).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      });

      controller.expectOne(url).flush({}, { status: 200, statusText: ''} );

      controller.verify();
    }));

    it('should call loader service completeLoading on error', async(() => {
      const url = faker.internet.url();

      httpClient.get(url)
        .subscribe(
          () => {},
          () => {
            expect(mockLoadingService.completeLoading).toBeCalledTimes(1);
          });

      controller.expectOne(url).error(new ErrorEvent(faker.random.words(3)), {
        status: 500
      });
      controller.verify();
    }));
  });
});
```

In the last two tests the `expect` statement in the tests is being called before the `finalize` operator in the interceptor and I can't figure out why. I was under the impression that the http call doesn't return until the interceptor has completed.

If I add `pipe(delay(1000))` to the second test it will work but that is wrong. Doing that in the third test makes no difference.

I am hoping someone can explain this to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you thing that `next` and `error` handlers should be executed after `finalize`?

Comment: @yurzui - Do you know why they are executed before because that is what I am asking? The interceptor is supposed to transform the stream so why would ```finalize``` be called after the http response is returned - or am I completely misunderstanding this?

Comment: Because finalizy is called when observable completes or gets error.

Comment: Okay, I think I just misunderstood how the http request pipeline works. After digging through the Angular source code it turns out that the interceptors run inside an Observable of the http request so ```finalize``` doesn't get called until the http request Observable completes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it helps to re(read) the documentation and source code. I was thinking that the tests needed to be asynchronous because a normal http request is asynchronous but the `HttpTestingController` emits synchronously. The tests need to be written like:

```
    it('should call loader service completeLoading on success', () => {
      const url = faker.internet.url();

      httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe();

      controller.expectOne(url).flush({}, { status: 200, statusText: ''} );
      controller.verify();
      expect(mockLoadingService.completeLoading).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
```